# I want to show the pipeline summary on the dashboard

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-dashboard, postman-newman

I am creating an html viewer tab as a result of pipeline and this tab contains test result and code covarage for team. I want to show this tab effectively on the dashboard. It will be enough for me to reflect the code coverage on any base to the dashboard.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxmVF.png)
or
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjcnW.png)

Embeded source from Azure extensions didn't work for me because I don't want the whole screenshot
Likewise, I tried the code covarage tool, but it didn't work because I ran the test process with newman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no out-of-the-box widget to display the code coverage or your html tab.

But we do have widgets showing a trend of test results for selected pipelines.

[Test results trend (Advanced) (Analytics, Build or Release pipeline)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#test-trend-results)

[Test results trend (Build or Release pipeline)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#test-trend-results-advanced)

For more details about the available widgets, you could refer to this official doc: [Widgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/overview?view=azure-devops#widgets).

Regarding the widget showing the code coverage, you could try to use the extension: [Code Coverage Widgets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shanebdavis.code-coverage-dashboard-widgets&ssr=false&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.vssps.visualstudio.com%2F#overview).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would like to see the code covarage output in the test result specifically. When I try and configure the code covarage widget, I can't see any results .